# How to add title of axis in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, scatter-plot, axis-labels

I'm implementing a data visualization feature in a self design WEB application by using Highcharts, but now I'm facing a problem, that is I can not add title of axis on my chart, I've survey and tried, but it still doesn't working.

The following is my web of that, and the original source.

WEB:http://140.138.152.9/test3D.html

Original source: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-scatter-draggable

Answer (score 1):

You can add title to xAxis and yAxis in  this way.

```
yAxis: {
            title: {
                text:'here is Y Axis  title',

            }
       },
xAxis: {
            title: {
                text:'here is  X Axis  title',

            }
       }
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sx5d5zzL/)

Comment: Thanks, I think it can not work before is because of add other options in the code.